# Facebook C# SDK Login in Sandbox Mode Http vs Https

Tags: http, https, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-c#-sdk

I have created an application using c# SDK.

The canvas page `http://mywebsite/` is working fine and I made to accomplish what the client wants, but when i try to access the application via **https:**//apps.facebook.com/ApplicationName which creates an iframe to `http://mywebsite/`, the login gets stuck.

This is what appears when I hit connect: 
[image]

That is the permissions window, the permissions appear, I hit ok, and nothing happens.

Code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
       // alert("aqui estoy");
        FB.init({
            appId: '397613493644598', // App ID
            status: true, // check login status
            cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML
        });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
                // app, and response.authResponse supplies
                // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
                // request, and the time the access token 
                // and signed request each expire
                var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
                //alert("conectado");

                // Do a post to the server to finish the logon
                // This is a form post since we don't want to use AJAX
                var form = document.createElement("form");
                form.setAttribute("method", 'post');
                form.setAttribute("action", '/Home/Login');

                var field = document.createElement("input");
                field.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                field.setAttribute("name", 'accessToken');
                field.setAttribute("value", accessToken);
                form.appendChild(field);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();

            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                  alert("Not Authorized");
                // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
                // but has not authenticated your app
              } else {
                  alert("Not logged In");
                // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
            }
        });
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    } (document));
</script>
<fb:login-button perms="user_birthday,email"> Connect</fb:login-button>
```

I may know what the problem is, but I need confirmation.

**Does the problem is that facebook apps address is https and my app canva url is http?,**

Comment: Yes, if you want to publish app in the facebook; your app (website) must be hosted in SSL certified domain (https).

Comment: Thank you Sahil! But this happens even I am using the sandbox mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, if you are testing stage, and this happens to you, you can do the following action.

Go to this link https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security

And disable secure browsing (this is just while you publish your app). Then your app should work fine.

Once you are ready to buy a certificate, and publish your application, Enable again this feature.

So the answer to my question:
**Does the problem is that facebook apps address is https and my app canva url is http?,**

is **YES**